# uwsgi segmentation fault when using flask and python requests

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, uwsgi

I'm running a dev uwsgi server using flask and a call to requests.get is triggering a segmentation fault in the uWSGI process.

Segmentation Fault:

```
!!! uWSGI process 70490 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 70490 ***
0   uwsgi                               0x000000010b394c70 uwsgi_backtrace + 48
1   uwsgi                               0x000000010b3951b3 uwsgi_segfault + 51
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff82784eaa _sigtramp + 26
3   ???                                 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
4   libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff914d2aa0 xpc_connection_resume + 192
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91fbb9d1 _CFPrefsWithDaemonConnection + 353
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91f8aae6 __66-[CFPrefsSearchListSource generationCountFromListOfSources:count:]_block_invoke + 150
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91f8a883 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource generationCountFromListOfSources:count:] + 179
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91e39cb4 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyDictionary] + 324
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91e3498c -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 60
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91fbc64c ___CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainer_block_invoke + 60
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91f89750 +[CFPrefsSearchListSource withSearchListForIdentifier:container:perform:] + 608
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91fbc5c7 _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainer + 183
13  SystemConfiguration                 0x00007fff92301aab SCDynamicStoreCopyProxiesWithOptions + 163
14  _scproxy.so                         0x000000010bdac914 init_scproxy + 58
15  Python                              0x000000010b55aa90 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13533
16  Python                              0x000000010b55d541 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 489
17  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
18  Python                              0x000000010b55d541 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 489
19  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
20  Python                              0x000000010b55d541 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 489
21  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
22  Python                              0x000000010b55d541 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 489
23  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
24  Python                              0x000000010b55d541 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 489
25  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
26  Python                              0x000000010b5573c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
27  Python                              0x000000010b4fc2e5 PyFunction_SetClosure + 828
28  Python                              0x000000010b4de202 PyObject_Call + 99
29  Python                              0x000000010b55a4ac PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12025
30  Python                              0x000000010b5573c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
31  Python                              0x000000010b4fc2e5 PyFunction_SetClosure + 828
32  Python                              0x000000010b4de202 PyObject_Call + 99
33  Python                              0x000000010b55a4ac PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12025
34  Python                              0x000000010b5573c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
35  Python                              0x000000010b55d4ae _PyEval_SliceIndex + 342
36  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
37  Python                              0x000000010b5573c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
38  Python                              0x000000010b55d4ae _PyEval_SliceIndex + 342
39  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
40  Python                              0x000000010b5573c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
41  Python                              0x000000010b4fc2e5 PyFunction_SetClosure + 828
42  Python                              0x000000010b4de202 PyObject_Call + 99
43  Python                              0x000000010b55a4ac PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12025
44  Python                              0x000000010b55d541 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 489
45  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
46  Python                              0x000000010b55d541 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 489
47  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
48  Python                              0x000000010b55d541 _PyEval_SliceIndex + 489
49  Python                              0x000000010b55a30c PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11609
50  Python                              0x000000010b5573c1 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1583
51  Python                              0x000000010b4fc2e5 PyFunction_SetClosure + 828
52  Python                              0x000000010b4de202 PyObject_Call + 99
53  Python                              0x000000010b4e8ff5 PyMethod_New + 1221
54  Python                              0x000000010b4de202 PyObject_Call + 99
55  Python                              0x000000010b524a33 _PyObject_SlotCompare + 2939
56  Python                              0x000000010b4de202 PyObject_Call + 99
57  Python                              0x000000010b55ce83 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 165
58  uwsgi                               0x000000010b3b0287 python_call + 23
59  uwsgi                               0x000000010b3b24b0 uwsgi_request_wsgi + 880
60  uwsgi                               0x000000010b346770 wsgi_req_recv + 288
61  uwsgi                               0x000000010b39292a simple_loop_run + 218
62  uwsgi                               0x000000010b399f7b uwsgi_ignition + 443
63  uwsgi                               0x000000010b399d73 uwsgi_worker_run + 883
```

uWSGI command:

```
uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8083 --ini uwsgi.ini
```

uWSGI ini

```
[uwsgi]
# this config will be loaded if nothing specific is specified
# load base config from below
ini = :base

# %d is the dir this configuration file is in
socket = %d/conf/app.sock
master = true
processes = 4

[dev]
ini = :base
# socket (uwsgi) is not the same as http, nor http-socket
socket = :8001


[local]
ini = :base
http = :8000
# set the virtual env to use
home=$dappenv


[base]
# chdir to the folder of this config file, plus app/website
chdir = %d
# load the module from wsgi.py, it is a python path from 
# the directory above.
module = app.application:app
# allow anyone int the group to connect to the socket.
chmod-socket=666
```

Offending code snippet:

```
def find_places_with_name(self, name):
    url = "{}/textsearch/json?query={}&key={}".format(
        self.api_url_root,
        name,
        self.api_key
    )

    #search_response = requests.get(url)
    # THE NEXT LINE IS THE LINE THAT BREAKS
    search_response = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
    if search_response.status_code != 200:
        # TODO throw/log
        pass

    return search_response.json()
```

Versions:

- Mac OS X 10.11.3
- uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit)
- Python 2.7.11
  (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 12:54:16)
- requests 2.9.1

Running the python code snippet directly from the command line works with no issues.

I reinstalled uwsgi and that didn't seem to work. I'm not super familiar with the intricacies of uWSGI configuration parameters. Is it possible that there is something in my configuration file that is causing this?

Comment: Try to add `enable-threads = true` to your uWSGI config. I've had that issue with uWSGI and requests lib and this solved my problem.

Comment: @GwynBleidD, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and still got the same segfault :-(.

Comment: Having the same issue. @zkk did you figure this out?

Comment: I had the same problem, added `enable-threads = true` and `threads = 2` gets rid of the error. However the request is never sent. Used [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) instead of uwsgi and it works fine with gunicorn.